# Transform text into formatted PDF?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, pdf, text

Does anyone know how to or have a good tutorial about converting text into a formatted PDF? I don't think the formatting would be too hard (put this text on that line... Etc.), but I have no idea where to even start to do the conversion. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ios+create+pdf).

Comment: The structure is too complex to do it simply but there are free libraries that can be incorporated into your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[iOS Developer Library: Generating PDF Content](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html).